# Java product of two arrays

Tags: java, arrays

I would like to resolve a problem for my homework. I have to multiply an array by itself using a method in Java that I created. However, my method doesn't work and I don't know why.

```
public static void initialiser(int mat[][]) {
    int i,j;
    for (i = 0; i < mat.length; i++) {
        for(j = 0; j < mat[0].length; j++) {
            mat[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }
}

public static int[][] produit(int mat1[][], int mat2[][]) {
    int i,j,k;
    int [][] matProduit = new int[mat1.length][mat2[0].length];

    for (i = 0; i < mat1.length; i++) {
        for(j = 0; j < mat2[0].length; j++) {
            initialiser(matProduit);
            for (k = 0; k < mat2.length; k++) {
                matProduit[i][j] =  mat1[i][k] * mat2[k][j];
            }
        }
    }
    return matProduit;
}
```

This is the result I should get:

```
0   1   0   0   0   0
0   0   1   0   0   1
0   0   0   0   1   1
0   0   1   0   1   0
0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0
```

This is the result I get:

```
0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Comment: I suggest debugging line by line and viewing the variables in real-time and you'll quickly see where it gets reset back to 0.

Comment: We have no information about that is given as an input.

Comment: `initialiser(matProduit);` resets your matrix to zeroes at every iteration...

Comment: @assylias You should answer the question as an answer, not as a comment.

Comment: No, the question is a trivial bug, and should be closed as such. The OP needs to debug first **before** posting his question here.

Comment: Additionally: `for(i) { for(j) {  mat[i][j] = 0; for(k) { mat[i][j] ` **+** `= mat1*mat2 } } }`

Answer (score 1):

As pointed by [Assylias](https://stackoverflow.com/users/829571/assylias) in the comments, you are calling    `initialiser(matProduit)` at each iteration, thus resetting your matrix to zero.

I would advise you to try the debug mode for those kind of problems. It is your top tool for your daily coding.

[Please find my own answer on another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39714788/how-to-debug-java-lang-arrayindexoutofboundsexception-in-a-java-program/39719862#39719862), adressing the debug, how to do it, activating it and using it at least correctly.

Comment: This seems more like a comment than an answer, as you're just pointing out what's wrong and aren't offering a solution.

Comment: I would have loved to provide him/her with a clear, detailled answer if she/he had answered our comments and questions in the first place. I'm doing my best so far.